# Make my code more modular to run multiple components at one time

Tags: javascript, html, arguments, modular

I have created a HTTP Response tracker which looks like a Traffic Light. Currently if the response is not a "200" response the traffic light flashes red. There is a request to a specific URL happening every 10 seconds and the traffic light will change accordingly e.g. Green for success, Flashing red for error.

The above works great but I have now ran into a problem where if I wanted to monitor multiple URLS with Multiple traffic lights on the same page I am restricted unfortunately as  I can only pass a URL Parameter and it will target all the .cp_trafficLight components.

I need to find a way to structure my code where I can pass an additional argument on the initializer to target specific .cp_trafficLight components.

```
    var requestResponses = {

    greenLight: $('.cp_trafficLight_Light--greenDimmed'),
    redLight: $('.cp_trafficLight_Light--redDimmed'),
    greenBright: 'cp_trafficLight_Light--greenBright',
    redBright: 'cp_trafficLight_Light--redBright',

    settings: {
        flashError: 400,
        requestTime: 10000
    },

    init: function (url) {
        requestResponses.url = url;
        requestResponses.getResponse(requestResponses.url);
        setInterval(function () {
            if (requestResponses.errorCode === true) {
                requestResponses.redLight.toggleClass(requestResponses.redBright);
            }
        }, requestResponses.settings.flashError);
    },

    successResponse: function () {
        requestResponses.errorCode = false;
        requestResponses.redLight.removeClass(requestResponses.redBright);
        requestResponses.greenLight.addClass(requestResponses.greenBright);
    },

    errorResponse: function () {
        requestResponses.greenLight.removeClass(requestResponses.greenBright);
    },

    getResponse: function (serverURL) {
        $.ajax(serverURL, {
            success: function () {
                requestResponses.errorCode = false;
                requestResponses.successResponse();
            },
            error: function () {
                requestResponses.errorCode = true;
                requestResponses.errorResponse();
            },
            complete: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    requestResponses.getResponse(requestResponses.url);
                }, requestResponses.settings.requestTime);
            }
        });
    },

    errorCode: false
}

requestResponses.init('/status');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/73tex200/1/

My code is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make a *factory function* :

```
function flashlight(el){
   //your code using el, instead of the green/yellow/red static identifiers thing
   return init;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
var url1=flashlight("test");
url(1"/testurl");
```

However, you need to modify your flashlight, so that it can be easily appended to an object,through  using sth like document.createElement...

Answer (score 0):

Add a second parameter to the init and set it to the html element that contains the lights.
Then, change the greenLight/redLight etc selectors to an object, so you can save multiple versions, one for each set of lights.
Have a function to get the 4 lights inside of this div.

Then, edit all your functions so you can pass the name around and change every peice of code that says `requestResponses.colorLight` to `this.instances[name].colorLight`.

Creating a class for this would also be a good solution, but if you don't like working with prototypes, something like this suffices.

This snippet isn't compelte, but it shows the basics of this style of solution.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cp_trafficLight" id="one">
            <div class="in">
                <div class="cp_trafficLight_Light cp_trafficLight_Light--greenDimmed"></div>
                <div class="cp_trafficLight_Light cp_trafficLight_Light--redDimmed"></div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="cp_trafficLight" id="two">
            <div class="in">
                <div class="cp_trafficLight_Light cp_trafficLight_Light--greenDimmed"></div>
                <div class="cp_trafficLight_Light cp_trafficLight_Light--redDimmed"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
var requestResponses = {
    instances : {},
    settings : {
        flashError: 400,
        requestTime: 10000
    },
    gather : function gather( container, url ) {
        var name = container.id;
        this.instances[name] = {
            callInterval: null,
            blinkInterval: null,
            url : url,
            errorCode: false,
            greenLight: $('#' + name + ' .cp_trafficLight_Light--greenDimmed'),
            redLight: $('#' + name + ' .cp_trafficLight_Light--redDimmed')     
        };
        return this.instances[name];
    },
    init : function ( url, container ) {
        var instance = this.gather( container, url );
        this.getResponse( instance );
    },
    successResponse : function ( instance ) {
        instance.errorCode = false;
        instance.redLight.removeClass( 'redBright' );
        instance.greenLight.addClass( 'greenBright' );
        if (instance.blinkInterval) {
            clearInterval( instance.blinkInterval );
        }
    },
    errorResponse : function ( instance ) {
        instance.errorCode = true;
        instance.greenLight.removeClass( 'greenBright' );
        instance.blinkInterval = setInterval( function () {
            console.log( instance.redLight );
            if (instance.redLight.hasClass( 'redBright' )) {
                instance.redLight.removeClass( 'redBright' );
                instance.redLight.addClass( 'redDimmed ');
            }
            else {
                instance.redLight.removeClass( 'redDimmed' );
                instance.redLight.addClass( 'redBright ');          
            }
        }.bind( instance ), this.settings.flashError );
    },
    getResponse : function ( instance ) {
        var module = this;
        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax(instance.url, {
                success: function() {
                    module.successResponse( instance );
                },
                error: function() {
                    module.errorResponse( instance );
                }
            });     
        }, this.settings.requestTime);
    }
}
requestResponses.init('/status1', $('#one') );
requestResponses.init('/status2', $('#two') );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So like this? I am running into an error. I understand your solution but it seems a bit foreign to how I imagined it being developed. If you could have a look I will thumbs up your answer

https://jsfiddle.net/73tex200/4/

Comment: I have updated the code shown, it should be syntaxerror free. I couldn't get the blinking to work on the fiddle alas, since the fiddle does strange things with context binding. COuld you try this version in a real browser and look at the errors, if any? Basically we created a module here, that behaves alot like a class. Writing it in class style would be 'cleaner' though. Do you know how prototypes and such work? If so, I might be able to update it to a prototype version ( as Jonas suggest with the factory comment ). (which will be easier to understand, IF you know prototypes) .

Comment: Hey Shilly, I really appreciate your help here but alas it is not working locally either unforunately. There is no errors but if you would like you can message me directly and I can send you a screenshot of what Ia m seeing. No blinking but a lot of objects being loaded instantly.